# Why does Twilio Twimlbin reject markup that uses voice="alice"?

Tags: twilio

I'm using Twilio Twimlbin to test some voice response markup and I don't understand why it's rejecting my markup as invalid TwiML.

Twimlbin rejects this markup:

[image]

but accepts this:

[image]

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested the above TwiML in twilio. The code works perfectly.

So the above code is a valid TwiML. This might be an issue related to Twimlbin's language validator. It's wise to trust twilio instead of a 3rd party tool.

Answer (score 1):

Both twiml specified above are valid.

[Check this for twiml say languages](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/say)